# How to determine $a,n$ for $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{ax^n+e^{\sin x}-[1+\ln{(1+x^2)}]\cos{x}}{x^4}$ so that the limit is nonzero?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, derivatives

My thinking process is that, using L'hopital's rule, we differentiate the equation $4$ times and every time before differentiation, we record what $ax^n$ (or $nax^{n-1}$ or so on) equals to keep the indeterminate form $\frac00$. But I encountered problem as I differentiate. I got $ax^n=1$, $nax^{n-1}=-1$ and $n(n-1)ax^{n-2}=-1$.... I don't think this solves the problem. Could someone provide a valid thought?

Comment: You would have to choose $a, n$ *s.t* the first term of the numerator is of the form $C x^4$. It is probably just as easy to assume $x$ is small and expand all the terms in the numerator. Unless there is some cancellation going on that isn't obvious, it is difficult to see this work out since you only have two variables $a, n$ to play about with.

Comment: If you use the above suggestion, then (making use of Wolfram to check your answer) have lim$_{x \to 0} e^{\sin x} - (1 + \ln(1 +x^2)) \cos x \approx x + \frac{5}{6} x^4 + ....$, so that your choice of $a$ and $x$ follows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$e^x=1+x+\frac{1}{2!}x^2+\frac{1}{3!}x^3+\frac{1}{4!}x^4+\ldots\quad\text{and}\quad\sin x =x-\frac{1}{3!}x^3+\frac1{5!}x^5+\ldots$$
We have
\begin{align*}
e^{\sin x}&=1+\left(x-\frac{1}{6}x^3+\frac1{120}x^5+\ldots\right)+\frac12\left(x-\frac{1}{6}x^3+\frac1{120}x^5+\ldots\right)^2+\frac16\left(x-\frac{1}{6}x^3+\frac1{120}x^5+\ldots\right)^3+\frac1{24}\left(x-\frac{1}{6}x^3+\frac1{120}x^5+\ldots\right)^4\ldots\\
&=1+x-\frac16x^3+\frac12x^2-\frac16x^4+\frac16x^3+\frac1{24}x^4+O(x^5)\\
&=1+x+\frac12x^2+\frac{13}{24}x^4+O(x^5)\tag{1}
\end{align*}
On the other hand
$$1+\ln (1+x^2)=1+x^2-\frac{1}{2}x^4+\ldots\qquad\text{and}\qquad \cos x =1-\frac{1}{2!}x^2+\frac{1}{4!}x^4+\ldots$$
Give us
\begin{align*}
[1+\ln (1+x^2)]\cos x&=\left(1+x^2-\frac{1}{2}x^4+\ldots\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{2!}x^2+\frac{1}{4!}x^4+\ldots\right)\\
&=1+\frac12x^2-\frac{23}{24}x^4+O(x^5)\tag{2}
\end{align*}
From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get
\begin{align*}
ax^n+e^{\sin x}-[1+\ln{(1+x^2)}]\cos{x}&=ax^n+x+\frac{3}{2}x^4+O(x^5)
\end{align*}
So it is needed $$ax^n+x=0$$
Which means $\color{blue}{a=-1}$ and $\color{blue}{n=1}$.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Just curious, what is $O(x^5)$